# How repeat %random% command in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to repeat a command in a batch file for limited times.This command:

```
echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random%
```

Not for unlimited! Just for e.x. 40 times **With different numbers**.

I tried the *For* command but it just gives same numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need delayed expansion.

compare the output of these two codesnippets:

```
 for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do @echo %random%
```

and

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do @echo !random!
```

Comment: The first one will repeat **a** number 10 times. But the next one is one what I want thanks!!!!